# Getting values as in order they added with NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am tring to populate a picker from a dictionary, and i have a dictionary

```
NSMutableArray* type1names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"--",@"AA",@"AB",@"BA",@"BB",@"BC",@"CB",@"CC",@"CD",@"DC",@"DD",@"FF",nil];
    NSMutableArray* type1points = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"-",@"4",@"3.7",@"3.3",@"3.0",@"2.7",@"2.3",@"2.0",@"1.7",@"1.3",@"1",@"0", nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *type1  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:type1points forKeys:type1names];
```

initialized like this. The problem occurs when i try to get them back as i put them into the Dictionary with the code below.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    YOHAppDelegate *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    NSString *key = [[app.pointsDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:row];
    return key;
}
```

They come back from dictionary unordered. Not random, always in same positions, but without any logical system.

Is there a way to implement this, or should i use multiple arrays for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Hot Licks said, NSDictionary does not save the order. However [Matt Gallagher shows how to create an OrderedDictionary](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html) by subclassing NSMutableDictionary.

On the other hand you should take his warning seriously. But the certain way, he subclasses it gives us a pattern, that can be used without subclassing: You can define a class, that holds an dictionary and an array, but inherits from NSObject. Define a `setObjectForKey:` method, that forwards to NSDictionary and add the object to the array (just, if it wasn't present in the dictionary). Add an method `objectForKey:`, that forwards to the dictionary and `objectAtIndex:` that forwards to the array.

Answer (score 2):

An NSDictionary has no (externally defined/documented) order for its elements.  If you want them ordered you need a different scheme.