# Order NSDictionary allObjects by Keys

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can i sort the NSDictionary on basis of key in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583020/can-i-sort-the-nsdictionary-on-basis-of-key-in-objective-c)

I have a several strings in a .plist file that I am trying to return into the NSDictionary then into an array but the order being returned isn't the same as I saved it in the playlist.
So far I have tried

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *strs = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dict allKeys]];
strs = [strs sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

but that is only returning the key names.

Comment: You can't order an NSDictionary, it is an inherently unordered object. You can order the keys like you did and loop through the ordered keys to get the values in that order, but that still doesn't order the dictionary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829119/getting-values-as-in-order-they-added-with-nsdictionary

Answer (score 0):

I actually was just looking through a few forums on google and found that this worked: [Can i sort the NSDictionary on basis of key in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583020/can-i-sort-the-nsdictionary-on-basis-of-key-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

You could keep an ordered array with your keys around as well, though.